# Replace parameters of certain shortcodes

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have the following text in a textarea:

```
<textarea class="content">
    [shortcode1 param1=test param2=john]
    [shortcode2 param1=test param2=john]
    [shortcode1 param1=john param2=exchange]
</textarea>
```

How I want to change the parameter names, but only if its shortcode1

So this should be the result:

```
<textarea class="content">
    [shortcode1 newparam1=test newparam2=john]
    [shortcode2 param1=test param2=john]
    [shortcode1 newparam1=john newparam2=exchange]
</textarea>
```

I currently use jQuery the following way:

```
$(".content").text($(".content").text().replace("param1", "newparam1"));
$(".content").text($(".content").text().replace("param2", "newparam2"));
```

But as you can see, it takes not only the params of shortcode1, but all.

Can somebody help me?
And is there a way to optimize the jquery part, because I have 10 of this replacements and may I can combine them?

Comment: The shortcode is executed in PHP, replacing it with javascript doesn't really make any difference, nor is it possible.

Comment: I not want to replace the shortcode with javascript, I want to replace a shortcode with an other shortcode, this done by javascript. See the code above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search (with indexOf) in each line (with split):

---

```
var text = $(".content").text().split("]");

for (var i=0, l=text.length; i<l; i++) {
    if (text[i].indexOf("shortcode1") >= 0) {
        text[i] = text[i].replace("param1", "newparam1").replace("param2", "newparam2");
    }
}

$(".content").text( text.join("]") );
```

Comment: Does this indexOf wents from "[" to "]" ? Edit: Ah I got it, its the split :)

Comment: Do you have an idea, how to solve this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832889/